# Humans have latent vampire abilities?

Tags: the-twilight-saga, breaking-dawn-2

In Twilight Saga Breaking Dawn - Part 2, after Bella is turned into a vampire, it's discovered she is a **"shield"**, able to nullify other vampires' abilities.
Edward realises that this is why he couldn't read Bella's mind when she was human.

I didn't understand this, a human exhibiting part of their vampire talent, (albeit a small part).
Is this explained at all, is it all humans or is Bella a special case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certain humans do, when Aro meets Bella he realizes he's unable to read her mind, and immediately is interested in what's she'll be like when turned to a vampire.

It's the same with other's like Alice who had her visions before being a vampire and thus was inside a mental institution; or Benjamin as it's stated on the books that Amun (leader of the Egyptian coven) met him prior to turning him into a vampire and realized his potential, therefore deciding to turn him into a vampire for that very same reason.

So overall **some** humans have latent abilities that manifest in it's fullest when becoming a vampire...